# Should we have a tag for WIP languages?

Tags: discussion, tags

As PLDI is a site about programming language design and implementation (crazy, I know), we will no doubt recieve questions from users who are developing their own programming languages and wish for feedback on their handling of a specific feature. Should questions like these have their own tag? If so, I suggest [work-in-progress](https://languagedesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/work-in-progress).

Answer (score 6):

## No tag

If you are posting here that means your language isn't done yet, or at least that you want to add more features. Adding a tag for that is redundant

Comment: Not necessarily; a lot of questions are about syntax, for example. What I'm asking is "should we have a tag for questions about the design of a new language".

Comment: Isn't every aspect of the design of the language either syntax or parsing or standard library or runtime or some other more specific tag?